# Get log from kernel while loading

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, logs, embedded

There is a arm/omap2-based device without ethernet, UART ports. It has usb connection with host, numeric keyaboard, LCD display. There is working U-Boot and kernel images for this.

I'm trying to made some little changes in linux kernel and deploy but there is some problem while kernel is loading and I can't receive any information while kernel is loading.

May somebody suggest, what steps are needed to receive this information.

Comment: There is a brand new StackExchange community called [Embedded Systems](http://embedded.stackexchange.com/). This is right up their alley (but be advised, it's new, and the community is small). Cross posting is not allowed, but if you don't get any good answers here, you can delete this one and post it there.